# google map does not appear but the search box does

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-maps

Google map does not appear but the search box does. I don't know what is the problem with this code. I even set `div` size which can be reason for not appearing on the screen. I didn't attach the CSS files. My code is given below:

HTML code:

```
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-cls-top " role="navigation"         style="margin-bottom: 0">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".sidebar-collapse">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
            </div>

            <div class="header-right">
                <img src="logo (1).ico" height="70px" width="70px" alt="Invite Logo">
                <img src="logo (2).ico" height="70px" width="70px" alt="Invite Logo">
            </div>
        </nav>

        <nav class="navbar-default navbar-side" role="navigation">

            <div class="sidebar-collapse">
                <ul class="nav" id="main-menu">
                    <li>
                        <div class="user-img-div">
                            <img src="user.png" class="img-thumbnail" />

                                <div class="inner-text">
                                Khadiza Kobra
                                </div>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a  href="check-in.html"><i class="fa fa-dashboard "></i>Maps</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="friends.html"><i class="fa fa-desktop"></i>My Circle</a>

                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a class="active-menu-top" href="#"><i class="fa fa-yelp "></i>Settings<span class="fa arrow"></span></a>
                             <ul class="nav nav-second-level collapse in">
                                <li>
                                    <a href="profile.html"><i class="fa fa-coffee"></i>Profile</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="account settings.html"><i class="fa fa-flash "></i>account settings</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a class="active-menu"  href="index.html"><i class="fa fa-send "></i>logout</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="notifications.html"><i class="fa fa-flash "></i>notifications</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="friends reviews.html"><i class="fa fa-anchor "></i>Friends reviews</a>
                    </li>
                    </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
        <div id="page-wrapper" >
            <div id="page-inner" >
                <div class="row">
                <input id="pac-input" class="controls" type="text" placeholder="Search Box">
                <div id="map"></div>
                <script>      
                 function initAutocomplete() {
                  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
                   center: {lat: 23.685, lng: 90.3563},
                   zoom: 13,
                   mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                   });
        var input = document.getElementById('pac-input');
        var searchBox = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(input);
        map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(input);
        map.addListener('bounds_changed', function() {
        searchBox.setBounds(map.getBounds());
        });
        var markers = [];
        searchBox.addListener('places_changed', function() {
         var places = searchBox.getPlaces();
          if (places.length == 0) {
            return;
          } 
          markers.forEach(function(marker) {
            marker.setMap(null);
          });
          markers = [];
          var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
          places.forEach(function(place) {
            var icon = {
              url: place.icon,
              size: new google.maps.Size(71, 71),
              origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
              anchor: new google.maps.Point(17, 34),
              scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(25, 25)
            };
            markers.push(new google.maps.Marker({
              map: map,
              icon: icon,
              title: place.name,
              position: place.geometry.location
            }));
            if (place.geometry.viewport) {
              bounds.union(place.geometry.viewport);
            } else {
              bounds.extend(place.geometry.location);
            }
          });
          map.fitBounds(bounds);
        });
        setMarkers(map);
      }
      var beaches = [
        ['Dhaka', 23.777176, 90.399452, 4],
        ['Mirpur 10', 23.8375, 90.3753, 5],
        ['Shahbag', 23.7381, 90.3954, 3],
        ['Dhanmondi 5', 23.7459, 90.3852, 2],
        ['MIST Mirpur', 23.8383, 90.3606, 1]
      ];
        function setMarkers(map) {
        var image = {
          url: 'map_icon.png',
          size: new google.maps.Size(20, 32),
          origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
          anchor: new google.maps.Point(0, 32)
        };
        var shape = {
          coords: [1, 1, 1, 20, 18, 20, 18, 1],
          type: 'poly'
        };
        for (var i = 0; i < beaches.length; i++) {
          var beach = beaches[i];
          var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: {lat: beach[1], lng: beach[2]},
            map: map,
            icon: image,
            shape: shape,
            title: beach[0],
            zIndex: beach[3]
          });
        }
      }
    </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBZlGIVcYhTwGPkeeZKj4GgcODjFps8y8U&sensor=true">
</script>                    

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

try adding a dimension to your map div eg:

```
  <div id="map" style="width: 400px; height:400px;></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You aren't calling the `initAutocomplete` function.  Either add &callback=initAutocomplete to the include of the API (remove `&sensor=true`, it is no longer required):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBZlGIVcYhTwGPkeeZKj4GgcODjFps8y8U&callback=initAutocomplete">
```

or call this:

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initAutocomplete);
```

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/wqj2txrk/)

**code snippet:**

```js
function initAutocomplete() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: {
      lat: 23.685,
      lng: 90.3563
    },
    zoom: 13,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  });
  var input = document.getElementById('pac-input');
  var searchBox = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(input);
  map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(input);
  map.addListener('bounds_changed', function() {
    searchBox.setBounds(map.getBounds());
  });
  var markers = [];
  searchBox.addListener('places_changed', function() {
    var places = searchBox.getPlaces();
    if (places.length == 0) {
      return;
    }
    markers.forEach(function(marker) {
      marker.setMap(null);
    });
    markers = [];
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    places.forEach(function(place) {
      var icon = {
        url: place.icon,
        size: new google.maps.Size(71, 71),
        origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
        anchor: new google.maps.Point(17, 34),
        scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(25, 25)
      };
      markers.push(new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        icon: icon,
        title: place.name,
        position: place.geometry.location
      }));
      if (place.geometry.viewport) {
        bounds.union(place.geometry.viewport);
      } else {
        bounds.extend(place.geometry.location);
      }
    });
    map.fitBounds(bounds);
  });
  setMarkers(map);
}
var beaches = [
  ['Dhaka', 23.777176, 90.399452, 4],
  ['Mirpur 10', 23.8375, 90.3753, 5],
  ['Shahbag', 23.7381, 90.3954, 3],
  ['Dhanmondi 5', 23.7459, 90.3852, 2],
  ['MIST Mirpur', 23.8383, 90.3606, 1]
];

function setMarkers(map) {
  var image = {
    url: 'map_icon.png',
    size: new google.maps.Size(20, 32),
    origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
    anchor: new google.maps.Point(0, 32)
  };
  var shape = {
    coords: [1, 1, 1, 20, 18, 20, 18, 1],
    type: 'poly'
  };
  for (var i = 0; i < beaches.length; i++) {
    var beach = beaches[i];
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: {
        lat: beach[1],
        lng: beach[2]
      },
      map: map,
      icon: image,
      shape: shape,
      title: beach[0],
      zIndex: beach[3]
    });
  }
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initAutocomplete);
```

```css
#map {
  height: 400px;
  width: 400px;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=geometry,places"></script>
<div id="wrapper">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-cls-top " role="navigation" style="margin-bottom: 0">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".sidebar-collapse">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
    </div>

    <div class="header-right">
      <img src="logo (1).ico" height="70px" width="70px" alt="Invite Logo">
      <img src="logo (2).ico" height="70px" width="70px" alt="Invite Logo">
    </div>
  </nav>

  <nav class="navbar-default navbar-side" role="navigation">

    <div class="sidebar-collapse">
      <ul class="nav" id="main-menu">
        <li>
          <div class="user-img-div">
            <img src="user.png" class="img-thumbnail" />

            <div class="inner-text">
              Khadiza Kobra
            </div>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="check-in.html"><i class="fa fa-dashboard "></i>Maps</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="friends.html"><i class="fa fa-desktop"></i>My Circle</a>

        </li>
        <li>
          <a class="active-menu-top" href="#"><i class="fa fa-yelp "></i>Settings<span class="fa arrow"></span></a>
          <ul class="nav nav-second-level collapse in">
            <li>
              <a href="profile.html"><i class="fa fa-coffee"></i>Profile</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="account settings.html"><i class="fa fa-flash "></i>account settings</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a class="active-menu" href="index.html"><i class="fa fa-send "></i>logout</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="notifications.html"><i class="fa fa-flash "></i>notifications</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="friends reviews.html"><i class="fa fa-anchor "></i>Friends reviews</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <div id="page-wrapper">
    <div id="page-inner">
      <div class="row">
        <input id="pac-input" class="controls" type="text" placeholder="Search Box">
        <div id="map"></div>
```